# SQL Server - WITH or Temp Table - TempDB Issues

Tags: sql-server

I am experiencing temp db issues and are looking at optimizing my queries to hopefully free up space on the TempDB.

So I have the following query (pseudo code) and am wondering if Example A. takes up more/less/ or the same space as Example B. or if there's a better solution all together.

**EDIT** the actual query is pulling 8+ fields, but they are all mapped by table 4's Identity ID column.

```
--(@PageSize/@PageIndex come in as parameters from the SP)
WITH data1 AS (
SELECT
t4.[id] AS [id],
t1.name1 AS [name]
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t1.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table1'
UNION
SELECT
t4.[id] AS [id],
t2.name1 AS [name]
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t2.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table2'
UNION
SELECT
t4.[id] AS [id],
t3.name1 AS [name]
FROM TABLE3 t3
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t3.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table3'
)
SELECT id, name
FROM data1
ORDER BY [id]
OFFSET (@PageSize * @PageIndex) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Example B

```
--(@PageSize/@PageIndex come in as parameters from the SP
CREATE TABLE #data
(
     [id]                  int,
     [name]                NVARCHAR(64),
);
INSERT INTO #data ([id], [name])
SELECT
t4.[id],
t1.name1
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t1.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table1';

INSERT INTO #data ([id], [name])
SELECT
t4.[id],
t2.name1
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t2.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table2';

INSERT INTO #data ([id], [name])
SELECT
t4.[id],
t3.name1
FROM TABLE3 t3
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t4.[systemId] = t3.[id] and t4.[systemType] = 'Table3'

SELECT id, name
FROM #data
ORDER BY id
OFFSET (@PageSize * @PageIndex) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Have looked at the queries in a optimizer, but unfortunately the TempDB performance isn't being monitored in our test environments.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` you aren't guarenteed to be getting consistent results anyway.

Comment: Since you don't seem care about getting distinct values, you can use UNION ALL for somewhat better performance. I would suspect query 1 would be better, unless you have some indexes on #data that improve the sorting performance (which you don't seem to use as @ThomA noticed)

Comment: can't do an offset without an order by, I've corrected the pseudo code.

Comment: Do you need to join on table4 btw, you could fetch values from table1,2,3

Comment: Yes, we need the join on table4. Tables 1,2,3 are from other source systems. Table 4 is used to gather additional information the original sources don't have and t4 has additional fields pulled in the actual query (that I left out from the pseudo code).

Comment: The only way to answer your question is to measure it - we can't predict what the execution plan will be for your queries because we don't have access to your database.

Answer (score 0):

A possible mitigation to your problem could do doing something like this:

```sql
create table #t_ids (id int, systemType varchar(30))
create clustered index IX_t_ids on #t_ids (systemType, id)

insert into #t_ids (id, systemType )
select t.id, t.systemtype
from table4 t
where t.systemtype IN ('Table1', 'Table2','Table3')
order by id
OFFSET (@PageSize * @PageIndex) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

select *
from #tid ids
inner join table1 t
  ON t.id = ids.id
  and systemtype = 'table1'
union
...
order by id
```

This way you skip the hard work on joins 'til later and you don't need to pull too much data prematurely. I'm not sure if it works with your queries since you didn't provide details, but it could.

Comment: I'll write up a query that does this, I'm meeting with our DBA (who has access to execution plans) tomorrow to discuss potential solutions.

Thanks for the suggestion.